# Facebook-API: get the liked Link or Photo of a "has liked a Link/Photo"-Response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Reading my own Feed in Facebook-API https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed with a valid Access-Token gives me the result shown below. How can i retrieve the Link, which was liked by me?

A similar Response i get when there was a Photo liked. How to determine the Photo-URL?

```
{
  "id": "xxxxxxx_yyyyyy", 
  "from": {
    "name": "XXX", 
    "id": "xxxxxx"
  }, 
  "story": "Peter likes a link.", 
  "story_tags": {
    "0": [
      {
    "id": "xxxxxxx", 
    "name": "Peter", 
    "offset": 0, 
    "length": 11, 
    "type": "user"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "type": "status", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Likes", 
    "id": "2409997254"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2012-09-21T21:31:06+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-09-21T21:31:06+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`me/feed` is an array of [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).
It's not the actual like but a post about that like.

There is now way to find out what you liked except to ask the application `like` from facebook itself which isn't possible.

If you want to know what kind of photos you liked recently, you have to go through all photos and see if you liked on and order it by date. That's not impossible to write in FQL but the facebook would never execute such a query in time. Trust me I tried ;)

Comment: No, it isnt. ['Application']['id'] is the ID of the Type of the record: a Like, or a Comment, a Photo, a Page etc.....

Comment: I updated the post a little. That should should do your question more justice.

Comment: Thats really a pitty, John. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @itinance don't forget to mark the answer, that will help others to find it.